# Debian / docker / aspnet core : SSL

Tags: angular, docker, debian, lets-encrypt, aspnetcore-environment

I meet some problems with my aspnetcore API's and Linux's environment.

I have an Angular project et 5 .net projects (API's and Worker Services) deployed for each of them in an docker container, all orchestred by a docker-compose.

I have a last Nginx container and I successfully certified my domain with "Letsencrypt" (docker image), that work's with my angular project.

But when I try to do request from the client to the aspnetcore API's (self-signed certificate), this doesn't work at all.

ISSUE => net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

So, I read many and many topics and articles about this issue, and I found this last article : https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificates-for-localhost/, that explain, we can't certified "localhost" , so we should declare our self-signed certificate in each browser.

So my question is : can I do that once for all and for every user want to access my website?

May be aspnetcore and linux are absolutely not compatible (especially for SSL).

What can I do? I am a bit lost now...

Comment: Can you post your nginx config? (Please clarify, you are serving just the angular static files from nginx or the api goes through also the proxy?)

Comment: Hi @C1sc0. Thank you for you response.

Yes, I serving only the angular static files. And I have an environmentApiUrls file in my angular project, store all urls. I call the urls and pass them in httpClient when I do a request.

Comment: Before I am trying to pass my website on https, all works fine on http. But now, my client is on https, and I have an issue (Mixed Content: The page at was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint . This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.), if I am trying to request an http endpoint. So I tried to also get a certificate for all my aspnecore API's, and I did it well. But it was a self-signed cert => doesn't work. Should I add all my API's containers to Ngninx ? I really don't know how to deal with this problem now..

Comment: You have to proxy connections to you API through nginx too, it will handle the TLS stuff, and in local connections it does not matter that it is just http (as an upstream).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proxy all your traffix through nginx and set the API as an upstream.

Example nginx config(add your already working TLS config to this):

```
worker_processes 1;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {

    sendfile on;

    upstream web-api {
        server mydotnetapi:80;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
        location /symbiosisapi/ {
            proxy_pass         http://web-api/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        }
        
        
        location / {
            autoindex on;
            root  /home/www-data/mysite;
        } 
    }
}
```

If someone hits the / location, it will receive the static stuff, and if someone hits the /api location the requests will be forwarded to your dotnet API. And nginx will handle all the TLS. Change the `mydotnetapi` to you container name what you set up in your compose file.

Comment: Than you so much @C1sc0 ! I will try your solution today, and I will give you a come back.

Comment: Hi @C1sc0 ! I come back to you for news. :)

I tried you solution, but I get a 404 not found now. I didn't understand why. I just write the container's api id in a stream like your exemple, and add it into a location in the server. I precise I have a letsencrypt certificate and a server listen 443 and ssl config.

Any idea?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi @Raikho did you succeed?

Comment: I think yes. I give you the link of my web site if you want check it may be ? https://symbiosis.ovh/

Comment: As you can see, if you try to connect (wrong name and password for the try is good), you can see a 404 not found when my client try to request my api.

Comment: The client is served through the same nginx server?

Comment: I mean, I succeed to link my statics angular frontend at nginx with ssl. But my aspnetcore api doesn't work at this moment.

Comment: Yes, the client and api are in the same server in nginx. It is a problem?

Comment: I c, `https://symbiosis.ovh/symbiosisapi/Login/Connexion` this path is the right one? (on your localhost this looks the same - except the domain)

Comment: As your exemple in this topic.

Comment: i see the problem, in the config that i sent you `location /api` this line tells the nginx which path forward to your api, so change this to `location /symbiosisapi`

Comment: Yes the path is the right one.

Comment: For details : 
- https://symbiosis.ovh = my domain
- /symbiosisapi = nginx location
- /Login/Connexion = api endpoint (controller + endpoint)

Comment: And as I mentioned, all are in a differents containers (nginx/angular/aspnetcore api). So in the upstream I write a proxy_pass => mycontainerIP:PORT

Comment: Change `proxy_pass         http://web-api;` this line to `proxy_pass         http://web-api/;` with a trailing slash

Comment: Oh ok !! That sounds good. I try that at miday and come back tou you. Thank you !

Comment: I've updated my answer (see the location part `location /symbiosisapi/` and  `proxy_pass         http://web-api/;` that way your api will get `https://symbiosis.ovh/Login/Connexion` (without the `symbiosisapi`)

Comment: Ok and what should my url looks like in angular? Still "ht tps://symbiosis.ovh/symbiosisapi/Login/Connexion" or "ht tps://symbiosis.ovh/Login/Connexion"?

Comment: yes,  symbiosis.ovh/symbiosisapi/Login/Connexion

Comment: Ok perfect ! Thank you so much C1sc0 !!! I give you a return of my tests.

Comment: Hi @C1sc0 ! I don't know if you are still here or not, but I have a question.

In fact, I have another PgAdmin container and I obtain a 502 bad gateway from Nginx.

I defined an upstream with the pgmadin container ip + port for in nginx. And I also defined a location for this up stream like this : location /pgadmin { }

Have you an idea?

Comment: Hi, and all containers are on the same bridge network?

Comment: Yes ! All are on the same network and all containers work fine.

Comment: I create earlier, a new topic here (for more details) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74045795/nginx-pgadmin-docker-502-bad-gateway?noredirect=1#comment130742047_74045795